# Complex Data structure in Java multi-level collections (lists) within one class

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections

I am relatively new to Java. I have been struggling to define a class that meets my needs. Searching on this site or google did not have probably because the question is so specific. Any help is appreciated!

Ideally the class (lets call it Filer) would have:

1. Name (string)
2. Volumes (Collection/list of Strings: 0 -100)
      Each Volume, in turn, will have:
      A. Name (string)
      B. Servers_Permed (another collection/list of Strings: 0-40)

Once I can get the class defined, I will do ok with defining getters and setters to use it, but so far I have failed to defined the class without getting totally lost :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that your description is not correct.

You need a class Filer with:

- name (String)
- volumes (list of Volume) (not strings as you asked, because you explained differently on the second part of the question, it is evident that you need a list of Volume and not a list of String)

And a second class Volume with:

- Name (string)
- Servers_Permed (list of strings)

So you need a data structure like the following:

```
public class Volume {
    private String name;
    private List<String> serversPermed;  // Changed the name to a name more adherent to standard guidelines

    ...
}

public class Filer {
    private String name;
    private List<Volume> volumes;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, lay it out piece by piece.

First, you have Volume (not sure how volumes could be "Collection/list of Strings: 0 -100" and have the following properties):

```
public class Volume {
    String name;
    List<String> servers_permed;
}
```

Now you have Filer:

```
public class Filer {
    String name;
    List<Volume> volumes;
}
```

you will have to add the necessary constructors, getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answer given above worked beautifully (they are almost the same anyway).

Thank you, Davide and DBug!